# ActiveMQ 5 Multi-Datacenter Cluster Sync

Tags: synchronization, activemq-classic, cluster-computing

We have the following configuration.

3 brokers in Datacenter A in a master/slave configuration using a shared file system.
3 brokers in Datacenter B in a master/slave configuration using a shared file system.

There are producers sending messages to topics at Datacenter A.  There are Camel routes routing those messages from the topics to separate local queues, 1 for local processing and 1 for remote processing, where another set of Camel routes route the messages from the local remote queue to remote queues at Datacenter B.

The same configuration exists at Datacenter B where the routing for the remote works in the opposite direction to Datacenter A.

This configuration is intended to give us an active/active multi-datacenter cluster.

Even though this configuration seems to work, we are wondering if this would be the recommended way to do this.  I am thinking in terms of using "network of brokers", but reading the documentation, it doesn't seem like that would accomplish what we are accomplishing with the Camel routes.

We do have problems from time to time, but we do not know for sure if the Camel routes are the cause.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the problems you are experiencing?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a consulting service. It's a place to ask programming questions. Please focus your question on a specific bit of code, explain what you expect it to do, what it is actually doing, and what you've done to try to fix it.

Comment: Is there a better place for this kind of discussion?  I'm seeing questions about ActiveMQ that are not about code in the Related section so I assumed this would be a viable place to get some insight from people who have used the technology longer than we have.